# Fallout-like Terminal system = matching each Char in string

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do is mimic a string based puzzle box like the Fallout terminals; ie each character in the password string is compared to each character in the possible mathcing option.
So if the password is Apple, it would be unknown to the player, but if they choose "App" the solution printout would be "3" or for "Appli" it should be 4.
However the following code is giving me issues
if I enter "Ap" my solution is 2

```
"App" = 4 
"Appl" = 5
"Appli" = 5
```

So the obvious issue is the double letters in a row.
I cannot seem to get around it using any word the user answers.
I have also tried turning both the "password" string and the user input string into lists and matching each character in each string against eachother but that has resulted in crashes.

private static string m_word = "Apple";

int count = 0;

```
try
{
    string attemptedWord = (e.Arguments[0]);

    foreach (Char a in m_word)
    {
        foreach (Char b in attemptedWord)
        {
            if( a != b )
                continue;
            else
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    } 

    e.Mobile.SendMessage("Count: {0}", count);
}
catch
{
    e.Mobile.SendMessage("invalid entry");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is for the user's "score" to reach the number of characters in the true password in a linear comparison:

```
string password = "apple";
string attempt = "appliance"; // change this to anything you want, see the result

int score = 0;
int goal = password.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < attempt.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == password.Length)
        break; // reached the end of the real password

    if (attempt[i] == password[i])
        score++;
    else
        break;
}

Console.WriteLine("Score: " + score);

if (score == goal && attempt.Length == goal)
    Console.WriteLine("You cracked the password!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly keeping with the spirit of your question, I would personally just use an existing edit distance algorithm like [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,considered%20this%20distance%20in%201965.). Obviously this calculates the inverse of your description, however you could easily minus the distance from string length to get your desired result.

> The Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the
> difference between two sequences. Informally, the Levenshtein distance
> between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits
> (insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word
> into the other.

**Given**

<sub>***Note** : This is not the bastion of perfect programming or algorithm implementation and it's slightly modified*</sub>

```
public static int Distance(string s, string t)
{
   // case insensitive 
   s = s.ToLower();
   t = t.ToLower();

   var n = s.Length;
   var m = t.Length;
   var d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];
      
   if (n == 0) return m;
   if (m == 0) return n;

   for (var i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++);
   for (var j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++);

   for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)  
      for (var j = 1; j <= m; j++)
      {
         var cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;
         d[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1), d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
      }
      
   return d[n, m];
}
```

**Usage**

```
var password = "apple";
int result;
string input ;
while ((result = Distance(input= Console.ReadLine(),password))!= 0)
   Console.WriteLine($"\"{input}\" = {password.Length - result}");

Console.WriteLine($"You won... something");
Console.WriteLine($"Game over");
```

**Output**

```
a
"a" = 1
s
"s" = 0
as
"as" = 1
app
"app" = 3
appl
"appl" = 4
apple
You won... something
Game over
```

<sub>***Note** : This is only an example and lacks any fault tolerance or sanity checks. You would need to add those things in a production environment.*</sub>